# Excluding values from an SQL Query that searches if a room is booked

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get a hotel booking system to return room id's (which I am using as room numbers) for rooms that are not booked and are a specific room size, in this case Single.

This is what I am currently using

```
SELECT * 
FROM rooms 
WHERE room_id NOT IN(SELECT room_id 
                     FROM room_bookings 
                     WHERE '2021/04/27' BETWEEN check_in_date AND check_out_date OR '2021/04/30' BETWEEN check_in_date AND check_out_date) 
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE room_size = 'Double')
```

Returning room id's that are currently not booked works, however I would like it to only return room id's that are Single, excluding the Double rooms altogether.

What do I need to add to this query to make it exclude double rooms?

```
CREATE TABLE `rooms` (
'room_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`room_size` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`floor_number` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `rooms` (`room_id`, `room_size`, `floor_number`) VALUES
(1, 'UNASSIGNED', 'UNASSIGNED'),
(2, 'Double', 'First'),
(3, 'Single', 'First'),
(4, 'Double', 'First'),
(5, 'Single', 'First'),
(6, 'Double', 'Second'),
(7, 'Single', 'Second'),
(8, 'Double', 'Second'),
(9, 'Single', 'Second'),
(10, 'Double', 'Second');


CREATE TABLE `room_bookings` (
`booking_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`room_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`manager_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`check_in_date` date NOT NULL,
`check_out_date` date NOT NULL,
`booking_date` date NOT NULL,
`room_size` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`lunch` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`dinner` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`price` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`booking_status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`payment_status` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `room_bookings` (`booking_id`, `customer_id`, `room_id`, `manager_id`, `check_in_date`, `check_out_date`, `booking_date`, `room_size`, `lunch`, `dinner`, `price`, `booking_status`, `payment_status`) VALUES
(9, 6, 1, 1, '2021-04-27', '2021-04-30', '2021-04-27', 'Double', '2', '2', '£230', 'Pending', 'test'),
(10, 6, 3, 1, '2021-04-29', '2021-05-04', '2021-04-27', 'Double', '3', '4', '£465', 'Pending', 'test'),
(11, 6, 7, 1, '2021-04-28', '2021-04-30', '2021-04-27', 'Double', '0', '0', '£120', 'Pending', 'test'),
(12, 6, 1, 1, '2021-04-29', '2021-05-04', '2021-04-27', 'Double', '2', '2', '£350', 'Pending', 'No Payment');
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The query is a “final version” of what I’ve tried so far, I’m stuck on excluding room ids that are assigned to a certain room size

Comment: `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE room_size = 'Double')` says: only return rows, if there exists no double room in the database. This is not what you want.

Comment: On a side note: `'2021/04/27'` is a string you are comparing with dates. This forces MySQL to convert this string into a date. This can work or not work. I don't know whether this would work with my German session settings. Better use date literals: `DATE '2021-04-27'`.

Comment: Thank you, it is only in this format at the moment as I am making sure the query works on phpmyadmin before implementing it into my final project, it will display dates in that format in the project. However I will keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this statement:

```sql
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE room_size = 'Double')
```

`NOT EXISTS` works by returning 'true' if the query returns 0 results.  As long as you have any room that is 'Double', the query will return results and the condition will fail.  To use this method you can link to the table in the subquery to single out the particular room by aliasing the 'rooms' table in your main query as 'r' and your subquery as 'd'.  This will ensure that there doesn't exist a 'rooms' row aliased as 'd' with the same row id you are looking at as 'r' in your main query and that has a size of 'Double'.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM rooms r
WHERE room_id NOT IN(SELECT room_id 
                     FROM room_bookings 
                     WHERE '2021/04/27' BETWEEN check_in_date AND check_out_date
                        OR '2021/04/30' BETWEEN check_in_date AND check_out_date) 
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT room_id FROM rooms d 
                      WHERE d.room_size = 'Double'
                        AND d.room_id = r.room_id)
```

Another option would be to use an 'in' clause like you do for booked rooms

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM rooms r
WHERE room_id NOT IN (SELECT room_id 
                     FROM room_bookings 
                     WHERE '2021/04/27' BETWEEN check_in_date AND check_out_date
                        OR '2021/04/30' BETWEEN check_in_date AND check_out_date) 
  AND room_id NOT IN (SELECT room_id 
                     FROM rooms
                     WHERE room_size = 'Double')
```

But you are already looking at the 'rooms' table in your main query, and `room_id` appears to be the primary key although it isn't shown as such.  If there is just one room with a particular `room_id` in the table, you already have access to the data in the row for the room.  So you can just filter on the `room_size` value for that row.  This will work as long as there aren't duplicate `room_id` rows with one being 'Single' and the other being 'Double'.  In that case the 'Single' row would still show up here:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM rooms r
WHERE room_id NOT IN (SELECT room_id 
                     FROM room_bookings 
                     WHERE '2021/04/27' BETWEEN check_in_date AND check_out_date
                        OR '2021/04/30' BETWEEN check_in_date AND check_out_date) 
  AND room_size <> 'Double'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining everything, of course the code works to

Answer (score 0):

You have a small error in your create TABLE rooms

You can union all roo_id that a re double

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    rooms
WHERE
    room_id NOT IN (SELECT 
            room_id
        FROM
            room_bookings
        WHERE
            ('2021/04/27' BETWEEN check_in_date AND check_out_date
                OR '2021/04/30' BETWEEN check_in_date AND check_out_date)
       UNION 
       SELECT  `room_id` FROM `rooms` wHERE
            room_size = 'Double')
```

Comment: Thank you, I think the sql for creating the tables got a bit messy when I exported it from the database, I just checked and everything is okay on mine. That query is exactly what I am looking for, it works perfectly. However, as it usually happens I also came up with something that also works between posting the question and you answering. Thank you very much anyway!

Comment: you can upvote helpfuöl answers, by the way mine is faster as the accetept

Answer (score 0):

Your `EXISTS` clause is inappropriate. You only want single rooms, so use `WHERE room_size = 'Single'`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM rooms 
WHERE room_size = 'Single'
AND room_id NOT IN
(
  SELECT room_id 
  FROM room_bookings 
  WHERE DATE '2021-04-27' BETWEEN check_in_date AND check_out_date 
     OR DATE '2021-04-30' BETWEEN check_in_date AND check_out_date
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also came up with this solution

```
SELECT * 
FROM rooms 
WHERE room_size = 'Single' AND room_id NOT IN(SELECT room_id FROM room_bookings
WHERE '2021/04/27' BETWEEN check_in_date AND check_out_date OR '2021/04/30' 
BETWEEN check_in_date AND check_out_date)
```

Answer (score -1):

Checkout the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM rooms 
WHERE room_id 
NOT IN(SELECT room_id FROM booking 
       WHERE '2021/04/27' BETWEEN check_in_date AND check_out_date 
       OR '2021/04/30' BETWEEN check_in_date AND check_out_date) 
AND room_size='double'
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not helpful. Please include context and explanation for all answers to make them useful for others.